# How to find Jordan basis of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, jordan-normal-form

Assume matrix

$$A=
\begin{bmatrix}
-1&0&0&0&0\\
-1&1&-2&0&1\\
-1&0&-1&0&1\\
0&1&-1&1&0\\
0&0&0&0&-1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Its Jordan Canonical Form is
$$J=
\begin{bmatrix}
-1&1&0&0&0\\
0&-1&0&0&0\\
0&0&-1&0&0\\
0&0&0&1&1\\
0&0&0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I am trying to find a nonsingular $P$, let $P=\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{p}_1&\mathbf{p}_2&\mathbf{p}_3&\mathbf{p}_4&\mathbf{p}_5\end{bmatrix}$ s.t. $J=P^{-1}AP\Leftrightarrow AP=PJ$.
I came up with the Wikipedia article on JCF and I think I need to find the generalized eigenvectors so that
$AP=PJ=\begin{bmatrix}-\mathbf{p_1}&\mathbf{p_1}-\mathbf{p_2}&-\mathbf{p_3}&\mathbf{p_4}&\mathbf{p_4}+\mathbf{p_5}\end{bmatrix}$ yielding the systems
$$(A+I)\mathbf{p_1}=\mathbf{0}$$
$$(A+I)^2\mathbf{p_2}=\mathbf{0}$$
$$(A+I)\mathbf{p_3}=\mathbf{0}$$
$$(A-I)\mathbf{p_4}=\mathbf{0}$$
$$(A-I)^2\mathbf{p_5}=\mathbf{0}$$

I solved each of these systems making sure that the vectors $\mathbf{p_i}$ I chose are linearly independent. So I chose
$$P=\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{p}_1&\mathbf{p}_2&\mathbf{p}_3&\mathbf{p}_4&\mathbf{p}_5\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1&2&-2&0&0\\1&1&2&0&1\\1&1&2&0&0\\0&0&0&1&1\\1&1&-2&0&0\end{bmatrix}$$
which even though is nonsingular I am not getting $AP=PJ$.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: are you sure for J? if so you can solve by the given hint

Comment: @gimusi I had a typo in matrix A when I typed in SE but now I fixed it. So the JCF is still the same matrix.

Comment: but how have you determined the structure of J? I've not checked,are you sure about it?

Comment: @gimusi As you probably know the JCF of the matrix is the same up to permutations of the Jordan blocks. But I used this specific structure typed here for my further calculations.

Comment: Yes, I'm asking if you are sure about the blocks. If so you can solve as indicated in the hint! Have you tried?

Comment: ok I've checked and it is right! thus what is the problem to find P?

Comment: @gimusi Have you read my whole post? Because I think I have already done what you suggested. So, I found $p_1$ then found $p_2$ so that is linearly independent with $p_1$, then $p_3$ linearly independent with all previous ones and so on. In this way, I found a nonsingular $P$ as stated in the post. But that $P$ does not satisfy the equation $J=P^{-1}AP$ and I cannot figure out what is wrong.

Comment: There is something wrong in your set up or calculation indeed from your results $Ap_1\neq p_1-p_2$.

Comment: @gimusi But can you check whether the 5 equations I setup to solve for $p_1,\dots,p_5$ are correct? If I understand correctly, I need to find $p_1,\dots,p_5$ that satisfy these equations but are also linearly independent. Is this true?

Comment: You set up seems ok and equivalent to mine, maybe you went wrong solving the systems, check again gor the calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the condition $AP=PJ$ is equivalent to

- $Ap_1=-p_1 \to p_1$
- $Ap_2=p_1-p_2\to p_2$
- $Ap_3=-p_3\to p_3$
- $Ap_4=p_4 \to p_4$
- $Ap_5=p_4+p_5 \to p_5$

Since the set up is equivalent, from you results seems that there is something wrong in the calculation indeed $Ap_1\neq p_1-p_2$.

Notably from

- $Ap_1=-p_1 \implies (A+I)p_1=0$
- $Ap_2=p_1-p_2\implies (A+I)p_2=p_1$

we obtain

- $p_1=(0,1,1,0,0)$
- $p_2=(-1,0,0,0,0)$

from

- $Ap_3=-p_3 \implies (A+I)p_3=0$

excluding $p_1$ we obtain

- $p_3=(1,0,0,0,1)$

and from

- $Ap_4=p_4 \implies (A-I)p_4=0$
- $Ap_5=p_4+p_5 \implies (A-I)p_5=p_4$

we obtain

- $p_4=(0,0,0,-1,0)$
- $p_5=(0,-1,0,0,0)$

Comment: So if I understand correctly, in order to find $p_1,p_2$ you jointly solve the first two systems and choose $p_1,p_2$ to be linearly independent then you choose $p_3$ so that it satisfies the 1st system and is independent of $p_1,p_2$ and finally you jointly solve the last two systems of equations to find $p_4,p_5$ so that all of $p_1,\dots,p_5$ are linearly independent. Correct?

Comment: $p_1$ and $p_2$ are not independent thus you need to find p_1 which satisfies also the system for $p_2$ while $p_3$ does not work, then we first havevto find $p_1$ and then $p_3$

Answer (score 0):

I got the Jordan blocks in slightly different order.

What you seem to be missing is the consistency part: in my

$$ P = 
\left(
\begin{array}{rrrrr}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

we have a place where we do have $(A+I)^2 p_3 = 0,$ **but we have consistency in that $p_2 =(A+I)p_3 .$** It follows automatically that $(A+I)p_2 = (A+I)^2 p_3 = 0.$

We also have $(A-I)^2 p_5 = 0,$ **then $p_4 =(A-I)p_5.$** As a result $(A-I) p_4 = 0.$

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rrrrr}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
-1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & -1 & 0 & 0
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{rrrrr}
-1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
-1 & 1 & -2 & 0 & 1 \\
-1 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & -1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{rrrrr}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0
\end{array}
\right) =
\left(
\begin{array}{rrrrr}
-1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}
\right)
$$

To get the Jordan form in the order they report, use my columns but permuted, $p_2p_3p_1p_4p_5$ and then correct $P^{-1}.$ We can correct $P^{-1}$ by permuting the **rows** to 23145.

Comment: I cannot see your point about consistency and why some order of Jordan blocks is better than another. I think that my setup is correct. How did you get $P$? Can you state all equations you solved?