# how to define a function over a Jordanizable matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I know that we can define a function $f$ over a matrix $A$ by doing the following, we diagonalise $A$ and then apply $f$ to all eigenvalues of $A$. After that we can perform a change of basis if we need our expression to be in a specific basis.

But what happens if the matrix cannot be written in a diagonal form, can I extend this definition? Do you any book that explains this? In $\mathbb{C}$ all matrices can be written in a diagonal form so I am wondering if there is a way to go back to $\mathbb{R}$ after applying $f$ but I am not sure if I am going on the right way. Thanks.

Comment: It depends on what we know about $f$.  If $f$ is analytic, then it suffices to apply a power series to the Jordan form.  If $f$ is merely continuous, we might run into trouble trying do define a functional calculus

Comment: Even in $\Bbb C$ not all matrices are diagonalizable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you begin with a real matrix $A$ and a one-variable real analytic function $f(x), \; $ you do get real $f(A).$

The Jordan part, $P^{-1}AP = J, \;$ is writing $J = D + N$ where $N$ is strictly upper triangular, and, because of the Jordan block description, $DN = ND.$ As a result, we can write $f(J) =f(D+N)$ using all available power series conveniences, along with the fact that $N^n = 0.$ The most common application is $e^{(D+N)t} = e^{Dt} e^{Nt} = e^{Nt} e^{Dt},$ where the entries of $e^{Nt}$ are explicit polynomials in $t.$

The part that I do not see many students writing correctly is just this, turn the thing around, $PJP^{-1} = A,$ finally $P f(J) P^{-1} = f(A).$ In order to do this, it is necessary to confirm that $P P^{-1} = I$ and both $P^{-1}AP = J, \;$ and $P f(J) P^{-1} = f(A).$ It is not enough to know the final Jordan form, you need the actual matrix $P$ and its correct inverse. Here is one from yesterday [How to find Jordan basis of a matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2688608/how-to-find-jordan-basis-of-a-matrix/2688690#2688690)

Reverse direction  $PJP^{-1} = A:$

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rrrrr}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0
\end{array}
\right) 
\left(
\begin{array}{rrrrr}
-1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{rrrrr}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
-1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & -1 & 0 & 0
\end{array}
\right) =
\left(
\begin{array}{rrrrr}
-1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
-1 & 1 & -2 & 0 & 1 \\
-1 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & -1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1
\end{array}
\right)
$$
$$ $$

**Worthwhile exercise for the reader: find $e^{At}$**

Comment: I see. Without the analytic condition $f(A)$ doesn't make sense. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

For a nilpotent operator $N : V \to V$ of index $m \in \mathbb{N}$ and an analytic function $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}z^n$ we can define $$f(N) = \sum_{n=0}^{m-1} \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}N^n$$

For an arbitrary linear map $A : V \to V$ with the minimal polynomial $(x - \lambda_1)^{p_1}(x - \lambda_2)^{p_2}\cdots (x - \lambda_k)^{p_k}$, the space $V$ admits the decomposition into generalized eigenspaces:

$$V = \ker (A - \lambda_1I)^{p_1} \dot+ \ker (A - \lambda_2I)^{p_2} \dot+ \cdots \dot+ \ker (A - \lambda_kI)^{p_k}$$

Notice that restricting $A$ to $\ker (A - \lambda_iI)^{p_i}$ we can write $A_i = A|_{\ker (A - \lambda_iI)^{p_i}}$ in the form

$$A_i = \lambda_i I_i + N_i$$

where $I_i$ is the identity on $\ker (A - \lambda_iI)^{p_i}$, and $N_i = A_i - \lambda_i I_i$, which is a nilpotent map of index $p_i$.

Therefore, having in mind Taylor's formula

$$f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(\lambda)}{n!} (z - \lambda)^n$$

we can define $$f(A_i) = f(\lambda_i I + N_i) = \sum_{n=0}^{p_i-1} \frac{f^{(n)}(\lambda)}{n!} N_i^n$$

So finally, for $A = A_1 \dot+ A_2 \dot+ \cdots \dot+ A_k$ we define

$$f(A) = f(A_1) \dot+ f(A_2) \dot+ \cdots \dot+ f(A_k)$$

Note that all definitions are in fact valid when $f$ is a polynomial, so this is simply a direct generalization to power series.